# How can I log in at one site and have it work for all subdomains?

Tags: mysql, authentication, subdomain

I'm trying to figure out a solution to a login problem. We have a main site, say example.com. There are multiple domains for different companies; company1.example.com, company2.example.com, etc. etc.

What I'd like is for users to be able to log in to example.com and be redirected to their correct website. So the main 'login portal' is on example.com, but after login they get redirected to their subdomain (which has its own database with a user table, etc. etc.).

This doesn't seem possible with the angle I'm coming at it from; how can the server know which subdomain and database to redirect the user to just from a simple login box (username and password)?

I suggested using a 'dropdown' to select the correct subdomain to log into, but the boss doesn't like that. Any other ideas?

Comment: Set the session's cookie domain.  How to do that will depend on the server-side language.

Comment: A question that StackExchange hasn't yet mastered.

Comment: Perhaps we could merge all of the users table into one table, and when users register at individial companies have it also log them with a 'master' table that has an extra field of the company they belong to..? Maybe? Eh.

Answer (score 0):

you can set session cookie (if using that) for domain with wildcard.
Better solution to create `auth.example.com` as SSO which will be logging in all users and validating all requests (look for OAuth).